# Generate WSS Signature Same as Soap UI giving different signature value Java

Tags: python, java, php, soap, soapui

I have tried many libraries to sign soap request body using jks file same way as soapUI with no success.
I were able to consume the soap service using request signed on soap UI but when follow same algorithm in have I got different Signature and handshake failed .
any one know package or code that make the signature exactly as SOap UI no necessarily in Java but any programming language

I tried to generate wss headers to soap request that match the one generated using soap UI
get different signature value

Comment: Post some code, please and focus on one specific language.